# Is there an Arabic Easter Egg in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos

I just observed something that I'm having trouble believing.

To push Lion onto my daughter's laptop without waiting for yet another giant Lion download, I turned on sharing on my MBP, connected from my daughter's SnowLeopard MB, and dragged.

While the copy was in progress, the file name label on the desktop was 'MacOSX Lion <arabic word>'. Once the copy finished, the Arabic disappeared.

Is the evidence of a special easter egg, a feature, or my need for better medication?

Comment: Maybe it is the fault of my Safari, but I don't see any Arabic in what you wrote.

Comment: I forgot to escape &lt; and &gt; in the text, and now there's a pending edit of someone else fixing it.

Comment: I think its just evidence of a packet being dropped when the filename was put in, or some such weirdness. Never seen the like but I have seen weird unicode stuff in filenames while they are not finished once in a great while.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when copying a large file, a temporary file will be created at the destination. The temporary file could be named `<actual file name> <some additional random data>`. Once the download completes, the temporary file is renamed to the actual file name.

I'm pretty sure Firefox behaves this way, but not certain whether Finder does. Also, I'm not sure why the suffix was in Arabic; perhaps the random data Apple uses is not limited to just `A-Za-z0-9`?

Interesting phenomenon nonetheless.